# How to use bunyan serializers

Tags: bunyan

I'm trying to use a custom serializer but it doesn't seem to work for me, my serializer is never called. What am I doing wrong?

I create a logger like this:

```
const mask = token => {
  console.log({token})
  return typeof token === 'string' ? token.replace(/[^\.]+$/, 'REDACTED') : token
}
const log = context.log = createLogger({
  name: '_placeholder',
  level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info',
  serializers: {authorization: mask, bearer: mask, Authorization: mask}
})
```

and then I log like this:

```
console.log({properties})
log[!status ? 'error' : status < 500 ? 'info' : 'warn']({error: merge({message, ...properties}, status && {status})})
```

Output piped to bunyan:

```
{ properties:
   { reason: 'InvalidToken', authorization: 'Bearer foo.bar.baz' } }
[2018-08-14T14:37:11.775Z]  INFO: _placeholder/9920 on XXX: 
   error: {
     "message": "Invalid token",
     "reason": "InvalidToken",
     "authorization": "Bearer foo.bar.baz",
     "status": 401
   }
```

EDIT:

I see it only works on top level properties; is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do here - mask nested properties aptly named?

Answer (score 0):

Well technically this works, but I'm not sure it's something I want to take live considering performance hit:

```
const jp = require('jsonpath')

class Sanitized extends Writable {
  write(object) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(
      ['authorization', 'bearer'].reduce((object, property) => {
        jp.apply(object, `$..${property}`, token => token.replace(/[^.]+$/, 'REDACTED'))
        return object
      }, merge({}, object))))
  }
}

...

const log = context.log = createLogger({
  name: '_placeholder',
  level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info',
  streams: [{type: 'raw', stream: new Sanitized()}]
})
```